# LAN in WiFi network and how to get IP address of all the connecting devices

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, networking, wireless-networking

I have two computers at my home and we use WiFi, how to LAN my both the computers? Is it required any special particular device or I need to configure it.

Secondly, how can I get the IP address of all the devices connected to the WiFi?

We use Windows OS on both the machines.

Comment: More info needed. Do you have a router with a DHCP server? If you have *only* 2 devices use static IP and then you always know what the IP addresses are.  Then ping them and if you get a response they are ON.(unless firewall blocks ping)

Comment: Once you have these IP addresses what do you want to do with them?  It will make a big difference in the complexity of the answer.

Comment: Want to share big files.

Answer (score 0):

The answer thankfully is simple.  Use the PC computer name.

```
If pc 1 is named  pc1-me
   pc 2 is named  pc2-other
```

You need to share the folder first
Create a folder.
Right click on it Sharing and Security.
To make it simple, for now, add the user everyone and give them Full Control.
You can create a new user assign a password and adjust the permission as you choose.

```
For testing on "pc 2" go to Start and Run type:
\\pc1-me\sharename
```

For a more permanent connection:
Right click on "Computer" or "My Computer" select "Map network drive"
path:  `\\pc1-me\sharename`

If you setup security then you need to use: "other credentials" check box and enter them and save the username/password.

If you setup up security (username,password, and/or file permissions) you will be prompted for it now.

Comment: Thanks for answer.Please let me check.. I will let you know if it works for me or not.